# Is Jahia 7 compatible with Oracle JDK 8

Tags: java-8, jahia

Since Oracle JDK 7 is no longer maintained for public, I want to run Jahia DigitalFactory 7.0.0 (Community/Entreprise) with Oracle JDK 8.

In Jahia's [prerequise and requirement](http://www.jahia.com/fr/home/resources/developers-downloads/prerequisite-and-system-requirem.html) there is only "JDK 1.6, 1.7" but noted as minimum. I know from experience that it we should run Jahia with an Oracle JDK (and not openJDK), but I was wondering if Jahia 7 runs on Oracle JDK 8 without any problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jahia Enterprise edition 7.0.0.5 and more recent are compatible with JDK 8 but the current community edition (7.0.0.0) is not.

However we are planning to release the new 7.1 version soon, in both community and enterprise edition, that will support JDK 8.

Best regards,
  Serge Huber