# Is Jahia 7 compatible on Debian 8?

Tags: debian, jahia

I would like to know if Jahla 7 is compatible with Debian 8. I have done some research myself but after looking around for a bit I haven't found my answer.

On the editor's website, i just found "linux compatible", and the forum is not accessible.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

jahia 7 should run fine on Debian 8.  Just install a JDK 7 or higher and you are good.

From here "[Is Jahia 7 compatible with Oracle JDK 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29984968/is-jahia-7-compatible-with-oracle-jdk-8)" Jahia Enterprise edition 7.0.0.5 and more recent are compatible with JDK 8 but the current community edition (7.0.0.0) is not.

Answer (score -2):

After some tests, and for those who might wonder the same thing as me, Jahia 7 runs fine on Debian 8.

Comment: @pagid: No, this is a self-answer. Not a particularly thorough one, but it's clear that it's not additional info, but a complete answer.